# Difference in memory use between std::string::clear and std::string = ""

Tags: c++, string, memory, std

Is there any difference (in relation to memory use) between:

```
std::string str = "{large string}";
str.clear();
```

and:

```
std::string str = "{large string}";
str = "";
```

Does any of options deallocate the old string?
(I think I remember seeing somewhere that `std::string` reserves the space it used before for further operations).

This question isn't a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388912/why-we-have-clear-function-when-we-can-assign-string-to-in-cpp) because I my question was to know if there is a difference in relation to memory use.

Comment: That answer doesn't answer my question because it doesn't say anything about memory use.

Comment: *Does any of options deallocate the old string?* --  You're assuming there was an allocation done.  Many, if not all `std::string` classes implement *short string optimization*, where no allocation is done if the initial string does not exceed a certain size.

Comment: In this case, I'm using quite big strings (>500 bytes at a minimum), so I presumed there would be an allocation.

Comment: Also, [CPPReference on clear()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear) states: *"Unlike for std::vector::clear, the C++ standard does not explicitly require that capacity is unchanged by this function, but existing implementations do not change capacity. This means that they do not release the allocated memory."* I.e. (as I would have expected), specific behaviour is implementation-defined.

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for the help! I'm then using `std::string::shrink_to_fit` after `std::string::clear` to remove the unnecessary capacity.

Comment: @RicardoAntunes: As you apparently *do* want to *reuse* that `string` object, wouldn't it be more efficient to *not* shrink it -- only to, probably in the next iteration, have the object run an allocation again when you're assigning the next big string to it? You shouldn't run this kind of optimization until you have *measured* a bottleneck to exist. (You know... measure, optimize, measure.)

Comment: @DevSolar you're right, but I'm not assigning the string very often. I was just shrinking it so it doesn't stay around in the memory wasting it. The truth is that it really isn't that important.

Comment: @DevSolar I think you mean implementation-specific, not implementation-defined. The latter means that the standard requires the implementation to document its behaviour.

Comment: @M.M: Ah. I found that "implementation-specific" is actually a thing in n4140... it isn't in the C standard's verbiage, where the closest you'd get would be "unspecified". You live and learn. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar actually I wasn't aware "implementation-specific" was mentioned in the standard either ... it seems to be the default term to use when talking about things that vary between implementations but aren't implementation-defined.